# JavaFX - Bind CheckBox status with disabledProperty without unidirectional binding

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx

I have a form in JavaFX with a bunch of fields, some of which are optional (and by default, disabled). In order to reflect that, I have a CheckBox next to each field that is linked to the `disabledProperty` of the corresponding field. However, since the property is related to the fact that the field is *disabled*, I have to link that property with the *negative* of the selection status:

```
BooleanProperty property = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);   
contentField.disableProperty().bind(property.not());
property.bind(chkBox.selectedProperty());
```

So, `property` is a `BooleanProperty` bound to both relevant properties.

The problem is that my model needs to be selectable programmatically, to support features such as clearing the selection (i.e. setting all the check boxes to false and conversely disabling all the content fields). Since the binding is done only in one direction, I cannot do `property.set(false)`, because it returns `java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.`

My question is: can I have a better binding model? Important for me is that the logic is controlled by the model (i.e. the `property`) rather than setting observers in the view (e.g. observe the status of the check box and change the status of the control), because I feel this can be very error prone and kinda goes against the JavaFX approach to MVC.

Comment: Doesn't `property.bindBidirectional(chkBox.selectedProperty())` solve the issue? Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: Thank you. Somehow, of all the binding approaches I tried, I missed that one. I must do more extensive testing, but it seems it works.